# Elastic Beanstalk deploy hooks: getting user's username

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Is there a way to get the username of the AWS user who initiated EB deployment from within a deploy hook?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's possible with AWS CLI command and apply filters to CloudTrail logs. But it has a few limitations.

Like CloudTrail is not real-time, it updates your logs approximately after 15 minutes which ultimately will a very slow deployment.